# Where is the realWorld# defined?

Tags: haskell, ghc

In the definition of `unsafeDupablePerformIO` ([source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.html#unsafeDupablePerformIO), [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO)) I found a reference to the one and only `realWorld#`. So I wondered where all these functions or values that end with a `#` are defined? I already found the [GHC primops](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/prelude/primops.txt.pp) of course: they include `seq#`, `catch#`, `retry#`, and all other kinds of interesting functions. It also contains a `RealWorld` type. But the primops don't seem to contain the actual value `realWorld#`.

```
{-# NOINLINE unsafeDupablePerformIO #-}
    -- See Note [unsafeDupablePerformIO is NOINLINE]
unsafeDupablePerformIO  :: IO a -> a
unsafeDupablePerformIO (IO m) = lazy (case m realWorld# of (# _, r #) -> r)
     -- See Note [unsafeDupablePerformIO has a lazy RHS]
```

(please don't mix `RealWorld` and `realWorld#`: the first is a type, the second is a value.)

Are there other undocumented primops in GHC? Or maybe all of this is documented somewhere, and I just haven't found it yet? Where in the GHC source can I look at the implementation of these things?

Comment: `realWorld#` and the models of `IO` and `ST` it supports are a terrible hack that almost certainly wouldn't exist if GHC were being designed today. It was the best the designers could come up with at the time, but now we know better ways. It's usually best to pretend those don't exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`realWorld#` is a value of type `State# RealWorld` which is a token that acts as a reference to "the real world". (Interestingly, it is of size 0 and does not occupy any space on the stack or heap.)

A bit of background information. `State# RealWorld` values represent the entire external runtime state of the program. The "real world", as it were. The `main` value in your program receives a `State# RealWorld` value that is threaded through the `IO` actions that compose it. `realWorld#` is that value at the time the `unsafeDupablePerformIO` value is evaluated.

As to where it's defined, it's [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/basicTypes/MkId.hs#L1061), for whatever good that will do you. :)